# Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, trigger, errors

````
SQL> create table master(pno number(5) primary key,pname varchar2(20),price number(10,2),stock
number(5));
Table created.
SQL> create table trans(p_no number(5),no_pro_sold number(5));
Table created.
SQL> insert into master values(&product_no,'&product_name',&price,&stock_in_hand);
Enter value for product_no: 1
Enter value for product_name: cd
Enter value for price: 700
Enter value for stock_in_hand: 6
old 1: insert into master values(&product_no,'&product_name',&price,&stock_in_hand)
new 1: insert into master values(1,'cd',700,6)
1 row created.
SQL> /
Enter value for product_no: 2
Enter value for product_name: dvd
Enter value for price: 600
Enter value for stock_in_hand: 9
old 1: insert into master values(&product_no,'&product_name',&price,&stock_in_hand)
new 1: insert into master values(2,'dvd',600,9)
SQL> /
Enter value for product_no: 3
Enter value for product_name: vcd
Enter value for price: 600
Enter value for stock_in_hand: 7
old 1: insert into master values(&product_no,'&product_name',&price,&stock_in_hand)
new 1: insert into master values(3,'vcd',600,7)
1 row created.
SQL> select * from master8;
PNO PNAME PRICE STOCK
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
 1 cd 700 6
 2 dvd 600 9
 3 vcd 600 7
SQL> create or replace trigger t1 after insert or update on trans for each row
  2  declare
  3  cursor c1 is select * from master where pno=:new p_no;
  4  begin
  5  for i in c1 loop
  6  if i.stock<:new.no_pro_sold then
  7  raise_application_error(-20001,'no.of product more than stock,error');
  8  end if;
  9  end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors. ```

How do I solve this problem
````

Answer (score 2):

Knowing how to debug your own code is important.

Try running `show errors` in SQLPlus.

It should tell you that something is wrong with line 3.

The rest is easy to fix.